# How to position element far right of web page, not browser page?

Tags: css, position

I am trying to position an element to the far right at the top of my web page. I was originally using position:absolute. However, after testing the website on a computer with a lower resolution, it scrolls the whole page correctly, but the element is positioned right of the browser - not the actual page - so when I scroll to the right, the element also scrolls, so it's not directly at the end of the page.
Is there anyway javascript could solve this problem to find the width of the web page and position the element at the far right?
Thanks

Comment: wouldn't `position: absolute; right: 0;` do exactly this?

Comment: No, as I said, absolute right only pushes it to the right of the browsers page, if you have more outside of the screen, it will scroll along with the screen. Not stay put.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the problem correctly:

```
<style>
    .stick-to-right {
        width: 250px;
        float: right;
    }
</style>
<div class="stick-to-right">Content</div>
```

Comment: That would work for a specific div yes. But I want it to be positioned at the far right of the page, and if the browser resolution is bigger for it to be the far right of that. I'm thinking perhaps some kind of javascript that gets the web page's width, and positions it far right of that?

Comment: Hmm that's what this does, position it on the far right of the screen, however wide the screen may be.

Comment: But you've given it a 250px width. Doesn't that mean it will just position it to the far right of the 250px? Not the whole screen?

Comment: That's the width of the div. Compare it to the width of the monitor, which will then be aligned to the right of your desk :P

Answer (score 4):

If you have a container/wrap DIV around your whole web page then make this element position:relative then place the DIV you want at the right of the web page inside this with position:absolute, right:0, top:0 on it. Hope that helps.